# No touchpad after fresh install

Tags: 12.04, touchpad

I installed 12.04 64-bit on a 120GB SSD. I rebooted after installation (no errors so far) and the mouse is not working.

I tried `depmod` but this throws an error:

```
/lib/modules/*****_generic is missing
```

etc...

Putting the normal HDD back to my laptop everthing works fine.

Comment: What mouse are we talking about?

Comment: i'm sorry. it's my touchpad (laptop)